# Seriously elusive for loop (racking my brains!)

Tags: python, for-loop, python-2.7, iteration

I've got a loop issue in Python 2.72 that's really frustrating me.  Basically the loop is not iterating on the first index `j`, and I've tried all sorts of ways to fix it with no luck.

```python
def learn(dataSet):
    for i in dataSet.getNext():
        recall = raw_input("Enter all members of %s you are able to recall >>> (separated by commas)  " % (i.getName()))
        missed = i.getMembers()     
        missedString = []       
        for a in missed:
            missedString.append(a.getName())
```

Here is the loop I can't get to iterate. The first for loop only goes through the first iteration of `j` in the split string list, then removes it from `missedString`.  I would like for all members of the split-string `recall` to be removed from `missedString`.

```python
for j in string.split(recall, ','):
    if j in missedString:
        missedString.remove(j)
        continue
for b in missed:
    if b.getName() not in missedString:
        missed.remove(b)
print 'You missed %d.  ' % (len(missed))
if (len(missed)) > 0:
    print 'Maybe a hint or two will help...' 
    for miss in missed:
        remind(miss.getSecs(), i.getName(), missed)
```

How can I fix the above code?

Comment: When you enter `recall`, are you also entering any spaces after the commas?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  I don't think that's the issue, but that's one thing I checked for

Answer (score 5):

`missedString` is a terrible name for a **list**

Note that you can simplify your code in a few places

```
        missedString = []       
        for a in missed:
            missedString.append(a.getName())
```

can be replaced by a list comprehension

```
        missedString = [a.getName() for a in missed]
```

Here you should just use the `split` method of `recall` instead of `string.split`). It looks as though this loop is supposed to be nested inside the `for i` loop, so I will assume it is (If it's not, you will be using the wrong value of recall with the wrong dataset).

```
for j in string.split(recall, ','):
    if j in missedString:
        missedString.remove(j)
        continue
```

It can also be replaced by a list comprehension.

```
recall_set = set(recall.split(','))
missedString = [j for j in missedString if j not in recall_set]
```

This will not work properly if eg. the user enters extra spaces in the input, so it's a good idea to `strip()` those elements

```
recall_set = set(s.strip() for s in recall.split(','))
missedString = [j for j in missedString if j not in recall_set]
```

This loop has a serious problem. In general it's not a good idea to remove elements from the list you are iterating over. You'll end up skipping over some elements without checking them

```
for b in missed:
    if b.getName() not in missedString:
        missed.remove(b)
```

Maybe a list comprehension can help again

```
missed = [b for b in missed if b.getName() in missedString]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, your post was extremely helpful.  Issue resolved, and I'll feel much more comfortable with list comprehensions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
for j in string.split(recall, ','):
    if j in missedString:
        missedString.remove(j)
        continue
```

try adding an

```
    else:
        print 'Didn't remove "%s"' % j
```

(And get rid of the `continue`. It's not serving any purpose).

You probably are missing some whitespace from your split. If that's the case, add a `j = j.strip()` or use `re.split(r'\s*,\s*', recall)` in place of `string.split(recall, ',')`.

Comment: This helped!  I didn't consider the extra white space, split is a much better choice.  Thanks!